# How to use 'replace' function in PostgreSQL to string replace

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do string replace in some data in `pgsql` database column. I tried

```
CASE
    WHEN (po.siteid IS NOT NULL) THEN replace('po.html_content', 'abcd', 'xxx')
        ELSE pc.html_content
 END
```

I want to replace string in `po.html_content` column. But above code is not working. Query get the data in  `po.html_content` column without replacing. 
Is my code is wrong or any idea...

Comment: You should show some the data that isn't being processed as you expect.  The output of `SELECT po.html_content, replace(po.html_content, 'abcd', 'xxx') FROM po` showing some of the rows where it hasn't been replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't enclosed the column name in a single quote**, in that case, it is not a column anymore but a regular string.

```
CASE
    WHEN (po.siteid IS NOT NULL) THEN replace(po.html_content, 'abcd', 'xxx')
    ELSE pc.html_content
END
```

Comment: @miuranga can you post the whole query?

Comment: @miuranga do you want to update the row or only select the row?

Comment: @miuranga are you aware that `REPLACE` is *case sensitive*?

Comment: I think it is lower case. I get it from PGSQL doc
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: @miuranga no, that's not what i mean. for example you have value of `HELLO world`, if you try to execute this: `replace('HELLO world', 'hello', 'not')` the result is nothing since `HELLO` is not the same as `hello`

Comment: @miuranga [See this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/453) showing `Replace` is case sensitive.

Comment: oh...I see. That not a problem. replace text in lower case

Comment: @miuranga, please post your answer next time. StackOverflow also serves as an FAQ, so people with similar problems don't have to post them again.